# Saving background color of rich textbox in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, textbox, load, save

Currently I am saving the contents of my rich textbox as so:

```
private void asRTFToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SaveFileDialog saveFile1 = new SaveFileDialog();
            saveFile1.DefaultExt = "*.rtf";
            saveFile1.Filter = "RTF Files|*.rtf|TXT Files|*.txt";
            if (saveFile1.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK &&
               saveFile1.FileName.Length > 0)
            {
                telep.SaveFile(saveFile1.FileName, RichTextBoxStreamType.RichText);
            }
        }
```

And loading it as:

```
private void rTFToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFileDialog openFile1 = new OpenFileDialog();
            openFile1.DefaultExt = "*.rtf";
            openFile1.Filter = "RTF Files|*.rtf";
            if (openFile1.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK &&
               openFile1.FileName.Length > 0)
            {
                telep.LoadFile(openFile1.FileName, RichTextBoxStreamType.RichText);
            }
        }
```

How can I save and load the background color of my rich textbox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using registery

```
`private void SaveSettings()
{
        RegistryKey R = Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey("RTF box");
        R.SetValue("FontName", textBox1.Font.FontFamily.GetName(0));
        R.SetValue("FontSize", Convert.ToString(textBox1.Font.Size));
        R.SetValue("ForeCol", Convert.ToString(textBox1.ForeColor.ToArgb()));
        R.SetValue("BackCol", Convert.ToString(textBox1.BackColor.ToArgb()));
        R.SetValue("WordWrap", Convert.ToString(textBox1.WordWrap));

}`
```

instead of textbox use functions of rich text box

Comment: So how do I get this into RTF files.

Comment: I do not want to use the registry. I want to be able to access files using the dialog. The rich text box saves the text color/font/ect. Of the rich text box, I also want to be able to save the background color of it as well. Any ideas?

Comment: sorry i forgot the question but RTF documents each piece of text can have its own color, font and size so you can't save them. the background colour can be saved by the same method above but replacing textbox functions with richtextbox functions